# How does one visit a cult leader Vissarion?

Tags: russia, religion, off-road, siberia

This is perhaps a strange question but I'm curious if anyone knows more about it or if there's any chance someone here has been there. Somewhere in Siberia is a religious cult leader of the name [Vissarion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vissarion). There have been many articles and documentaries about him - namely a [documentary by Vice](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W2Cv5hZfOmk) and [an article](http://www.vice.com/read/the-mysteries-of-the-teacher-0000099-v18n12).

I know that it's possible to travel and see the place, but I'm having trouble finding specific information on how to actually do so. Does anyone know more about travelling to the settlement of *Tiberkul* in the *Taiga*?

Comment: I'll be forever grateful! No rush. I'm only planning on making the trip in March/April.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First of all, [*Taiga*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taiga) is very big thing, so address *in the Taiga* isn't much helpful for you :)
Secondary, my apologies about some information is only in Russian, especially maps.

The Curch of the Last Testament has their village in the [Krasnoyarsk Krai](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krasnoyarsk_Krai). Their site is very old, and the only thing working there is the [main page](http://www.vissarion.ru/). Also they have [international website](http://www.vissarion.eu/), and there is the [location of them](http://album.vissarion.eu/en/Album%201.html).

[Official postal address](http://www.vissarion.ru/church/contact/index.htm) is:
662925, Krasnoyarsk Krai, Kuraginsky District, d. Petropavlovka, ul. Kolhoznaya, d. 9.

Please note that Tiberkul is named after [lake Tiberkul](http://turizm.ngs.ru/local/sights/1289/), which is situated in 130 kilometers from Kuragino (district center) and in 30 kilometers from Cheremshanka village.
Other villages near the lake are: Tagasuk, Zharovsk, Gulyaevka.

[image: map]

According [this](http://turizm.ngs.ru/local/sights/1289/) and [this](http://www.bylkov.ru/forum/47-1087-1), the roads to the lake is available ONLY IN WINTER - on snow (from Gulyaevka and Cheremshanka). In other time, you can get there only by two methods:

- helicopter
- local citizens's tankets and tractors :)

Also [here](http://www.3ton-club.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?t=120) is some information about some club in [Abakan](http://maps.google.ru/maps?q=Respublika%20Khakasiya,%20Abakan&hl=ru&ie=UTF8&sll=53.605544,93.235474&sspn=2.594604,5.020752&oq=Abakan&gl=ru&hnear=%D0%90%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD,%20%D0%A0%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%A5%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F&t=m&z=12), which regulary goes to the lake on their off-roaders, but this is quite uncertain.

Comment: Thank you! This is great.. a lot of information I didn't know about. Looks like it will be pretty difficult to get there but at least it's possible.

Comment: @bryceadams Many people goes there to fish on the lake, so you have time to make some contacts there to easy your way. Good luck with that.